# How to Carry Ldap settings in Jboss EAP 6.4 from Websphere 7.0

Tags: ldap, settings, jboss6.x

I am trying to make the same settings that I have in Websphere 7.0 for LDap connection, on JBoss EAP 6.4

I read alot about it on red-hat portal and also on stackoverflow and other sources but still I couldnt make it work.

On Websphere I have these settings with the same order.

```
    User filter:
    (&(|(cn=%v)(samAccountName=%v))(objectclass=user)) 

    Group Filter:
    (&(cn=%v)(objectclass=group)) 

    User ID map:
    *:CN 

    Group ID map:
    *:CN
```

On Standalone.xml I have these lines, which I think is wrong.

```
        <security-realm name="LDAPRealm">
            <authentication>
                <ldap connection="ldap_connection" base-dn="ou=users,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com">
                    <advanced-filter filter="samAccountName=%v"/>
                </ldap>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <ldap connection="ldap_connection">
                    <username-to-dn>
                        <advanced-filter base-dn="ou=users,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" user-dn-attribute="cn" filter="samAccountName=%v"/>
                    </username-to-dn>
                    <group-search group-name="SIMPLE" iterative="true" group-dn-attribute="dn" group-name-attribute="uid">
                        <group-to-principal search-by="DISTINGUISHED_NAME" base-dn="ou=groups,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org" recursive="true">
                            <membership-filter principal-attribute="memberOf"/>
                        </group-to-principal>
                    </group-search>
                </ldap>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```

So, I need to make the jboss settings exactly as the Websphere, but I couldnt make it for 2 days now. I am totally new on this era.

I have the RBAC enabled as access control provider. What I am expecting is nbeing asked for login and after I entered the credentials I need it to be validated from this LDap server and let me get in.

Thank you in Advance.